# Show that DFP update preserve Positive Definiteness?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

The update for Davidon-Fletcher-Powell (DFP) is given as the following:

$$
B_{k+1} = (I - \rho_ky_ks_k^{\top})B_k(I - \rho_ks_ky_k^{\top})+\rho_ky_ky_k^{\top}
$$

where $y_k,s_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\rho_k=y_k^{\top}s_k>0$ and $B_ks_k=y_k$.

Show that when $B_k$ is positive definite so is $B_{k+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then

$$x^{\top} B_{k+1}x  = x^{\top}(I - \rho_ky_ks_k^{\top})B_k(I - \rho_ks_ky_k^{\top})x+\rho_kx^{\top}y_ky_k^{\top}x.$$

As $B_k$ is positive definite, we have

$$ x^{\top}(I - \rho_ky_ks_k^{\top})B_k(I - \rho_ks_ky_k^{\top})x \geq 0.$$

Moreover,

$$ \rho_k x^{\top}y_ky_k^{\top}x \geq 0.$$

Hence, $$x^{\top} B_{k+1}x \geq 0.$$

To show that $B_{k+1}$ is positive definite, it remains to show that the inequality is strict when $x \neq 0$, or equivalently, $x^{\top} B_{k+1}x = 0$ implies $x=0$.  From above $x^{\top} B_{k+1}x = 0$ implies $$(I - \rho_ks_ky_k^{\top})x = 0,$$ and $$y_k^{\top}x =0.$$

But this implies $x=0$. Hence, $B_{k+1}$ is positive definite.

Comment: Why this true $ x^{\top}(I - \rho_ky_ks_k^{\top})B_k(I - \rho_ks_ky_k^{\top})x \geq 0.$
?

Comment: $B_k$ is positive definite, hence $z^{\top} B_{k}z \geq 0 \ \forall z$. You can choose for $z$ the vector $z =  (I - \rho_ks_ky_k^{\top})x$

Comment: $z$ is not the same!!!!!!

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The first one is $y_ks_k^{\top}$ whereas the second one is $s_ky_k^{\top}$ which makes them different.

Comment: I see. When you take $z =  (I - \rho_ks_ky_k^{\top})x$. Then $z^{\top} =  x^{\top}(I - \rho_ks_ky_k^{\top})^{\top} = x^{\top}(I - \rho_ky_ks_k^{\top}).$

Comment: Please edit your proof because what you have written is for positive semi definite matrices while we are after positive definite.